# How to separate two pairs without using and?

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions

I have written the following sentence, but I think that I should use an **"AND"** between *"down"* and "Success", on the other side, by doing so, the phrase would become rather ugly and awkward (3 "and" among 4 words), should I use a **comma** or something like **"as well as"**? and what about the rest of the sentence. Is it academic for a SOP?

Throughout my personal and professional careers, I have encountered ups and downs, success and challenges, which have made me well experienced in handling problems in critical situations.

Comment: [please note: made me well experienced is not idiomatic at all]. Also: what is a personal career? Do you **mean** personal **life** and professional career?

Comment: @Lambie After reading your kindly comments, I have become aware of the logical problem of the sentence. So, I have changed it as following: Throughout my professional career, I have encountered ups and downs, successes and failures, which have made me well-skilled in ameliorating critical problems.

Answer (score 2):

The strategy you have adopted, in which *success and challenges* acts as a supplement to *ups and downs*—in effect, it "renames" *ups and downs*—is entirely proper to a rhetorical genre like an SoP.

However, *success and challenges* is not strictly parallel to *ups and downs*.

- Both components should be plural—*success**es** and ...*
- *Challenges* is not really polar to *successes* as *downs* is to *ups*. A *challenge* is something you may either succeed or fail to rise to. It's really sort of weaselly here; a sophisticated reader will take it to mark your unwillingness to admit that on occasion you have actually ***failed*** to rise to a challenge. FumbleFingers' suggestion, *successes and setbacks*, is admirable.

Comment: okey, I got your point, what about "successes and failures"? does it make more sense?

Comment: A better "restatement" of ***ups and downs*** would be ***successes and setbacks*** (or ***...and failures***, but I like the alliteration of repeated initial "s"). Plus ***setback*** is slightly more "euphemistic" than ***failure***, which might matter to OP.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Really nice. I've stolen it.

Comment: While I was writing the comment I put "alliteration" in scare quotes, cos I was thinking "it's a pretty weak example of the device", but I knocked them out before actually posting, cos I thought I already had too many quote marks in the text. It's only after your comment made me look at this again that I realised it's actually quite a strong alliterative coupling, on account of the ***four*** preceding ***s*** sounds in ***successes***. (I was a poet but I didn't know it, as they say! :)

Comment: I really don't understand how one can answer the "and" part of the question while allowing the remaining bits to stay as is. personal career? make me well experienced?

Comment: @Lambie I quite agree -- but that's not the primary question, and addressing "the rest of the sentence" would take us into the deprecated realm of proofreading. :)

Comment: Yes, but then the OP goes off, correcting what s/he has just learned and leaving the rest all wrong. I dunno, but I see that as problematical.

Comment: @ Lambie  you are right man. Actually, I didn't notice this delicate point. so , I have changed the sentence as following:

Comment: Throughout my professional career, I have encountered ups and downs, successes and failures, which have made me well-skilled in ameliorating critical problems.

Answer (score -1):

Use "as well as" in place of "and".

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20well%20as):

> **as well as** conjunction
>   : and in addition : AND
>   // brave **as well as** loyal

Comment: *As well as* is not equivalent to *and*: it marks a parenthetical, not a conjunct.

Comment: @StoneyB That's not at all true. That's *one* way it's used, but not the only way. The first sense of the phrase at [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20well%20as) is "and in addition : AND  // and brave as well as loyal."

Comment: *And in addition* ≠ bare *and* either. Yes, you see both phrases used this way, usually as a sort of [elegant variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elegant_variation) on *and*, but they are not equivalent. Phrases headed by complex prepositions like *as well as* and *(and) in addition (to)* can be moved; true conjuncts cannot.